# How do I keep Photo Stream photos separate from imported photos in iPhoto?

Tags: iphoto, apple

I keep most of my photos organized using Expression Media, but it is very easy to manage photos from my iPhone in iPhoto. However, when I click on Photos under library it shows the images from Photo Stream alongside the photos that I import from my iPhone. I am using iPhoto 11 on a MacBook Pro.

I have searched for details on this but keep coming up empty handed. Is there a way to view the two sources separately? Ideally I would like to see Photo Stream and Imported.

Is there any documentation that helps clarify this?

My ears and mind are open.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some additional research and finally figured it out. With Photo Stream photos are automatically downloaded into iPhoto and you can view all Photo Stream photos by clicking on the Photo Stream link in the sidebar.

Thinking that the Photo Stream photos were actually only in iCloud I had been importing photos from my iPhone and iPad into iPhoto making duplicates of everything. when I realized that I was duplicating everything I confirmed that the Photo Stream photos were actually downloaded to my computer I deleted the duplicate imported images. I now have a nice tidy photo set that is uniform across devices.